# Mapping two unrelated representation spaces with different distributions, roughly preserving similarities

Tags: neural-network, data, representation

I've got two embedding / representation spaces which are completely unrelated to begin with, yet I wish to find a (=any) mapping between them.

Space A are feature histograms with a somewhat normal distribution (size 30 vectors).
Space B are sparse feature indicator vectors (size 150) with roughly 12-15 1s each.
I've got around 6000 datapoints and ultimately want to predict new samples in space B from new samples in space A, its okay if this mapping doesn't convey all information as long as it preserves distance/similarity from space A in space B by some metric.

This sounds like a contrastive / triplet / cycle problem, however I thought I'd ask if someone might recommend a simpler solution to begin with. I also don't have classes, and 'every' sample from space A can be valid (no major outliers or heavily skewed histograms will appear here), whereas I've got 6000 positive and 20000 negative samples from space B if that helps.

Any advice?